# Can I install Ubuntu 14.04.1 alongside Windows 8.1 on a Lenovo y510p?

Tags: 14.04, boot, dual-boot, windows-8, uefi

I recently tried to install Ubuntu (64bit) onto my Lenovo y510p. I partitioned 150GB of space, created a UEFI boot device with my flash drive, and was able to load into a live version of Ubuntu. My problem comes when I get to the install screen where it asks how it should install Ubuntu (by erasing the current disk, installing alongside, etc...). It doesn't give me the option to install alongside Windows. I tried the "try something else" option and attempted to select my free space partition but it said there was no root device and told me to fix it in the partition menu. I then read somewhere that Lenovo computers cannot run both operating systems alongside each other (it wasn't clearly worded but that was my interpretation).

While I'd like to say I know my way around a computer this is my first time attempting to dual boot, and have little idea what I'm doing.

Comment: Maybe something [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2175814) will help?

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI   and:  http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system Be sure to backup Windows first, use Windows to shrink the NTFS partition and reboot immediately so it can run chkdsk and repair its new size.

Answer (score 0):

you should really look up into Ubuntu installation procedure. Why would you install Ubuntu alongside Windows if you already have a separate partition for it? You should use **something else** option.

It is possible to install both OS on Lenovo computer. I did it on my Y580 laptop.

Well, you provided not so many informations. Was Windows pre-installed? How many partitions do you have (active/primary)? Can you format your partition before trying to install Ubuntu?

I have just updated this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported), but I think you should really look into Ubuntu installation procedure. Watch some explanatory video.